# Why can't I see my patch on Call of Duty: Modern Warfare while I'm playing online?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

It started on level 12 Sargent I. All I saw was a green square in the spot where my rank's badge or "patch" is suppose to be. I  thought maybe there was a problem with that specific rank so I continued playing to see if it would begin to work again, but it has been 4 ranks and I am now a Gunnery Sargent II and it is still happening. Can anybody help me or tell me how to get my rank's badge or "patch" back?

Answer (score 1):

So, you are playing on ps3 right. I think you were in a "Hacked Lobby", and now your rank is buggy because of the hacks they used. This is not your fault, but i think you cant do anything against that. The only option you've got now, is to find another "Hacked Lobby" and clear your prestige to 0 or any other prestige. That worked on my Account very well but i dont know how to find loobys like that ( its random and not fun to play).